# Trying to select text within a cell in a table in Internet Explorer results in rest of table being selected

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a strange problem on a web page I'm working with. I have table with lots of information in it and when I try to select a single cell (click-drag) it selects that entire cell and the rest of the table.

I have checked the code over and over again and I cannot seem to find what is causing this problem. Other tables work just fine with selecting just a single cell or even text within a cell.

Double clicking the cell also works for selecting but since some of the cells have links in them that does not solve the problem.

Has anyone heard of a similar problem or know how to solve this?

Tables use `<table><tbody><tr><td>`-format and all tags are closed correctly.

Comment: Indeed, please post example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that content within an absolutely positioned div on a page with other absolutely positioned div's made the entire page be selected.

IE probably registers the first mouse down event within the Div, but when you start dragging it registers it outside the div, thus forcing the selection of the entire page from where you started dragging.